# Script not outputting results to text file

Tags: regex, perl, ubuntu

so i recently started using the `Ubuntu` operating system for various reasons and i become interested in the syslog that exists on the system.
I created a `perl` script that would search through the syslog for specific terms that could exist in the log using regex and print it out, but unfortunately while the code runs with no errors nothing actually is printed.

I can't seem to figure out why its not outputting the results of the search to the output file.

Heres what i got so far
Any help would be appreciated

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array=();
open(my $keyword,'<', "keyword.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

open(my $sys,'<', "syslog") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

#open($keyword,'>' "keyword.txt") || die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

#open my $keyword, '>' , $file_location3 or die "can't open Keywords:" $!;  # gives keywords.txt the file handle keyword and shows 
                                                                       #error message if it fails to open 
#open my $sys, '>' , $file_location2 or die $!; # same as above 

open(my $fh, '>', 'output.txt');

#my $file_location2 = "syslog";

#my $file_location3 = "keyword.txt";


#arraylisy goes here 
           

my $Keyword_or = join '|' , map {chomp;qr/\Q$_\E/} <$keyword>; # lists all lines in indicated file and joins the list in 1 string
                                                               #regex here removes new line from each line and uses literal regex
                                                               #which matches even those words with dots 
my $regex = qr|\b($Keyword_or)\b|; # this regex will match 
                                   #all the keywords stored in keywords txt file
#@array = $Keyword_or;

foreach $regex(@array)
{

    #while (/regex/g) 
    #{ 
      #print $NEW "$.: $1";
      print $fh $regex;

     #} 
     #return $keyword;
     #return $sys; 
     #return $NEW; 
     #print $fh $NEW;
     close $fh;

}
```

---

#### Update

Tidied and with the commented-out lines removed, that Perl code looks like this. Hugely more readable but clearly wrong

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ();

open( my $keyword, '<', "keyword.txt" ) or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
open( my $sys,     '<', "syslog" )      or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
open( my $fh,      '>', 'output.txt' );

my $Keyword_or = join '|', map { chomp; qr/\Q$_\E/ } <$keyword>;

my $regex = qr|\b($Keyword_or)\b|;

foreach $regex ( @array ) {

    print $fh $regex;

    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: `@array` seems to be empty?

Comment: It's really not clear from the code you've posted what you're trying to do. You at the least have an empty array you're trying to iterate whilst overwriting each element into `$regex` which you already defined

Comment: `$sys` is also nothing doing but opened

Comment: `@array = $Keyword_or;` you could not do this.

Comment: You want to `grep log file line` to be matched with `sys log file line by line` and want to be print the `matched line` in the `keyword.txt`. Is it write?

Comment: Cross-posted at [Perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1177387)

Answer (score 3):

There's a few possible problems.

- You `close $fh;` within the loop, which means you'll only ever print one result.
- You don't actually read anything into `@array` at any point, so it's empty.
- `foreach $regex ( @array ) {` probably isn't doing what you think. It's clobbering `$regex` and assigning it to each value of `@array` in turn - it's not doing a regex match.  (maybe you want to `grep`?)

Perhaps you meant something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $keyword, '<', "keyword.txt" )
  or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
open( my $sys, '<', "syslog" ) or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
open( my $output, '>', 'output.txt' );

my $regex = join( '|', map { quotemeta s/[\r\n]+//r } <$keyword> );
   $regex = qr/\b($regex)\b/;

select $output;    #set standard output to this file
while (<$sys>) {
   print if m/$regex/;
}

close($keyword);
close($sys);
close($output);
```

Note - the `r` flag to regex is a feature of perl 5.14. That's still pretty old, but there's older versions of perl around. You can workaround it if you need to by:

```
chomp ( my @terms = <$keyword> );
my $regex = join( '|', map { quotemeta } @terms);
```

Comment: There is no need to capture the regex. `$regex = qr/\b(?:$regex)\b/;`